# Why do I get a syntax error when trying to run a fab module?

Tags: python, syntax, fabric

I'm trying out fabric for the first time and I'm trying to run the hello world example from their documentation:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/tutorial.html

I've created a local file called fabfile.py which contains the below lines of code:

```
def hello():
   print("Hello world!")
```

Now I try to run it in the python interpreter:

```
> >>> import fabric
> >>> import fabfile
> >>> fab hello   File "<stdin>", line 1
>     fab hello
>             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> >>> from fabfile import hello
```

The 'from fabfile import hello' works, so it must see the file and the hello function as it errors if I try to do the same with junk keywords. However, then I try to run the code using the 'fab *function*' syntax, it throws that 'invalid syntax' error.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
If I try running it in the terminal directly it doesn't work either

```
[user@host folder]$ bash
[user@host folder]$ fab hello
No idea what 'hello' is!
[user@host folder]$ 
[user@host folder]$ ls
fabfile.py  fabfile.pyc  test-connect.py  TST_SYBASE.txt
```

Comment: I am assuming your are running unix of some kind and now windows btw...

Comment: Yep, using RHEL 7

Comment: Also, I suggested an edit to your title, as the issue scopes differently than just a syntax error. If you get a chance, feel free to peer review this edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST THING IS THE DOCUMENTATION FOR FABRIC IS OUTDATED**

[This is an open issue on git.](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1854)

`fabfile.py` needs to have the correct decorator:

```
from fabric import task

@task
def hello(ctx):
  print("Hello World")
```

**SECONDLY**

The documentation shows that `fab hello` needs to be executed at the higher level, in a `shell`, like `bash`.

Make sure you are in the `pwd` that has your fabric file.

Run `fab hello`.

This should look like this:

```
Twoodys-MacBook-Air:fabQ twoody$ ls
fabfile.py
Twoodys-MacBook-Air:fabQ twoody$ fab hello
Hello World
Twoodys-MacBook-Air:fabQ twoody$
```

Comment: Doesn't work either :(

[user@hostname folder]$ fab hello
No idea what 'hello' is!

Comment: Done :D
[user@hostname folder]$ ls
fabfile.py  fabfile.pyc  test-connect.py  TST_SYBASE.txt

Comment: @Lehliana You will want to take note of this `decorator`, as it is considered a high level feature of the python language. It is modifying the function `hello()` directly, by wrapping it with fluff, that I did not research myself. It looks like there is a lot of TODO's with your fabric journey though, so maybe do not get lost in the rabbit hole of decorators :p